# FileZilla fails to retrieve directory list if connected via quickConnect button via VPN

Tags: vpn, filezilla

Without VPN I can easily connect with the ftp via the Quickconnect button.
With VPN I must do a work around via the site manager.
Images numbered from 1 to 3 should make it clear.
Is there a sollution so I can still connect with the Quickconnect button when connected via VPN.

[image: Quickconnect without VPN]

[image: Quickconnect with VPN]

[image: Connecting via site manager via the vpn]

Comment: This is [not a programming question](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score -1):

The simple way would be to make changes to the FTP server end by changing the IP permitted to "Default".This would permit all IP addresses to use the server. Hope this answer helps.

Comment: Hello, together with my employer we look at the issue on site of server and networksite (Both seems not be possible to solve the issue). So only case rest is something on configuration on FileZilla site. Does anybody have a clue what we can change into the settings of FileZilla so we can make a connection via the QuickConnect button over VPN ?